When does the limit $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos (\frac x n)$ exist?
Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of complex numbers. Then for any $x\in \mathbb R$, the sum $S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos (\frac x n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges. To prove this, observe that $\cos (\frac x n) \sim 1 - \frac {x^2} {2n^2} \; (n\to \infty)$ for any $x$, so if $a_n\to 0$, then
$$
a_n( 1- \cos (\frac x n) ) \sim \frac{a_n x^2} {2n^2} = o\left(\frac 1 {n^2}\right) \implies \sum a_n(1-\cos(\frac x n)) \text{ converges.} 
$$
$$
\implies \sum a_n(\cos(\frac x n)) \text{ converges iff } \sum a_n \text{ converges.}
$$
And if $a_n \nrightarrow 0$, clearly both $\sum a_n(\cos(\frac x n))$ and $\sum a_n$ diverge.
Suppose for the rest of the question that $\sum a_n$ converges. Now I wish to study the behavior of $S(x)$ as $x\to +\infty$. The first thing to do is to test whether the limit $\lim_{x\to +\infty} S(x)$ exists. Intuitively, it can never exist unless all $a_n$ are zero because $S(x)$ should oscillate indefinitely at $\infty$. But how to prove it?
I've already known that if $0<\sum |a_n|<\infty$ , then indeed $\lim_{x\to +\infty} S(x)$ cannot exist. Assume the contrary that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} S(x)=A$. By Weierstrass M-test, the absolute convergence of $\sum a_n$ yields uniform convergence of $\sum  a_n \cos(\frac x n)$. Thus, for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ and $X>0$ such that
$$\begin{align}
\left| \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \cos \frac{x}{n} -A \right| & \leq \left| \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \cos \frac{x}{n} - \sum_{m=n}^\infty a_n \cos \frac{x}{n} \right| + \left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos \frac{x}{n} -A\right| \\
   & < \frac \epsilon 2 + \frac \epsilon 2 = \epsilon
\end{align}$$
for all $x\in [X,+\infty)$. We see that the max distance between $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\cos(\frac x n)$ and $A$ is smaller than an arbitrarily small $\epsilon$. But when we compute their 'average distance', namely (note that $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\cos(\frac x n)$ is periodic with period $2N!\pi$),
$$ \left(\frac 1 {2N!\pi}\int_{X}^{X+2N!\pi} \left| \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \cos \left(\frac{x}{n} \right) -A\right|^2 \mathrm d x \right)^{1/2}= \left(\frac 1 2 \sum_{m=1}^{N} |a_n|^2 + |A|^2 \right)^{1/2} , $$
we see that the average distance is greater than a fixed positive number. But average distance is no greater than max distance (which is less than an arbitrary $\epsilon$), so we obtain a contradiction.
However, if $\sum a_n$ converges conditionally, such an 'averaging' approach doesn't seem to work. In this case $S(x)$ may not be uniformly convergent. For example, let $a_n=\frac {(-1)^n} {n^{1/2}}$. If $S(x)$ is uniformly convergent, then for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N\in \mathbb N$ such that for all $p$ we have
$$\left| a_N\cos(\frac x N) +\cdots + a_{N+p} \cos (\frac x {N+p}) \right|<\epsilon$$
holds uniformly for all $x\in \mathbb R$. Like the argument above, computing
$$ \left(\frac 1 {2(N+p)!\pi}\int_0^{2(N+p)!\pi} \left| a_N\cos(\frac x N) +\cdots + a_{N+p} \cos (\frac x {N+p}) \right|^2 \mathrm dx \right)^{1/2}$$
gives a contradiction. Hence for this particular $\{a_n\}$, $S(x)$ is not uniformly convergent. To prove nonexistence of $\lim_{x\to +\infty}S(x)$ by the averaging method, I guess we need at least that the partial sums are uniformly bounded. I seriously doubt this is even true.
So finally the question:
Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges conditionally. Must $\lim_{x\to +\infty} S(x)$ exist? When does it exist?

I would say that for all $x\in\mathbf{R}$, the series converges because, $$|S(x)|≤\sum_{k\geq 1}a_{k}$$ as $|\cos(x)|$ is bounded above by $1$ for all $x\in\mathbf{R}$. So everything depends on the infinite sum of $a_{k}$'s

@RAHUL Are you sure this is valid when $\sum |a_k|=\infty$?

ofcourse we may not be able to determine convergence of $S(x)$ when $\sum |a_{k}|$ diverges. But if it converges so does $S(x)$

Actually we are able to determine that $S(x)$ converges iff $\sum a_n$ converges, as showed in my first paragraph

I made an attempt have a look and let me know if any mistakes or improvements

Throughout this answer, we assume that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, so that $S(x)$ is well-defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, we give an elementary proof of:

Theorem. $S(x)$ converges as $x \to \infty$ if and only if $a_n = 0$ for all $n$.

Proof. Assume that $S(x)$ converges to some $A \in \mathbb{C}$ as $x \to \infty$. Define $R(x)$ by
$$ R(x) = \frac{2S(x) - S(x+2) - S(x-2)}{4}. $$
Then by invoking trigonometric identities, we get
\begin{align*}
R(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n \cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right), \qquad b_n = a_n \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
\end{align*}
Since the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges absolutely, $R(x)$ converges absolutely and uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$. This allows us to write:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} |R(x)|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \sum_{m,n \geq 1} b_m \overline{b_n} \cdot \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} \cos\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
Now we focus on the integral
$$ I_{m,n}(T) = \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} \cos\left(\frac{x}{m}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x}{n}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$
Clearly $|I_{m,n}(T)| \leq 1$. Moreover, it is easy to check that $I_{m,n}(T) \to \frac{1}{2}\delta_{m,n}$ as $T \to \infty$, where $\delta_{m,n} = \mathbf{1}[m = n]$ is the Kronecker delta. So by the dominated convergence theorem for series,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{T\to\infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} |R(x)|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \sum_{m,n \geq 1} b_m \overline{b_n} \cdot \lim_{T \to \infty} I_{m,n}(T) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |b_n|^2.
\end{align*}
However, the assumption tells that $R(x) \to \frac{2A - A - A}{4} = 0$ as $x \to \infty$, hence
\begin{align*}
\lim_{T\to\infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} |R(x)|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x
&= 0.
\end{align*}
Therefore $b_n = 0$ for all $n$, which then implies that $a_n = 0$ for all $n$.

The OP conjecture is true so assuming $\sum a_n$ converges hence $S(x)$ is defined and continuous, then $S(x)$ has a limit at infinity iff $a_n=0$ for all $n$.
From now on we work under the assumption $\sum a_n=a$ finite and $S(x)$ has a limit at infinity which per the answer of @Sangchul must be zero. Also let $M$ the finite maximum of $|a_n|$.
Note first that the representation $S(x)=a-2\sum a_n \sin^2 x/(2n)$, the boundness of $a_n$ and the inequality $|\sin z| \le c|z|$ when $|z| \le 1$ imply that the series above converges locally uniformly in the plane so $S$ extends to an entire function.
Also $|\sin z| \le \sinh |z| \le e^{|z|}$ so splitting the sum above in $1\le n \le |z|$ where we majorize each term by $Me^{|z|}$ and $n>|z|$ where we majorize each term by $c^2M|z|^2/(4n^2)$ gives us $|S(z)|\le |a|+|z|e^{|z|}+K|z|^2$ hence $S$ is an entire function of exponential type (order at most $1$ and finite type).
A clever application of Phragmen Lindelof (see the book of Boas on Entire Functions, Theorem $6.2.8$ gives the fact that if $S(x) \to 0, x\to \infty$, then $S(x+iy) \to 0, x \to \infty$ for every fixed $y$.
This immediately implies (loking at the imaginary part) that $\sum a_n \sinh y/n \sin x/n \to 0, x \to \infty$ for every fixed $y$ so in particular with $b_n=a_n\sinh 1/n$ which satisfy $b_n=O(1/n), \sum b_n =b$ converges we have $T(x)=\sum b_n \sin x/n$ (which converges absolutely and uniformly on compact subsets of the plane since $|\sin x/n| \le c|x/n|$ for $x$ in a compact set and $n$ large enough, while $b_n=O(1/n)$) also satisfies $T(x) \to 0, x \to \infty$ (on the positive axis).
The same argument as above shows that $T$ is an entire exponential so $T(x+iy)  \to 0, x \to \infty$ for every $y$. Again looking at the imaginary part we now get $\sum b_n \sinh y/n \cos x/n$ converges to $0$ when $x\to \infty$ and with $y=1, c_n=b_n\sinh 1/n$ so $c_n=O(1/n^2)$ hence $\sum |c_n|$ finite we have also $\sum c_n \cos x/n$ converges to zero and that implies $c_n=0$ (hence $a_n=0$ for all $n$) as shown in the OP (or by easy almost periodicity arguments) so we are done.

Proposition:-
Let $x>1$ be any real number and $N>1$ be any integer .If $A(N)=\sum_{n≤N}a_{n}$,
$S_{N}(x)=\sum_{n≤N}a_{n}\cos(\frac{x}{n})$. Then,
$$A(N)-\frac{π^{2}x^{2}}{12}≤S_{N}(x)$$
Proof:-
This follows from the series expansion of $\cos(x)$.
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots$$
$$S_{N}(x)=\sum_{n≤N}a_{n}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2n^2}+\frac{x^4}{24n^4}+\cdots\right)$$
Now we have that,
$$A(N)-\frac{x^2}{2}\sum_{n≤N}\frac{1}{n^2}≤S_{N}(x)$$
.Since $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}=\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$,
$$A(N)-\frac{\pi^2x^2}{12}≤S_{N}(x)  
 \blacksquare$$
Now it's very easy to see that if
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}A(N)\to\infty$$ then,
For any $x>1$
$\lim_{N\to\infty}S_{N}(x)\to\infty$
So coming to your question, if $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_{n}$ diverges so does $S(x)$.
